# Что означает Use Case в контексте архитектуры?

Tags: архитектура, терминология

Пытаюсь разобраться с архитектурой MVP и все чаще слышу Use Case.
Что оно значит? Википедия как-то не обьясняет.

Comment: Use case примерный дословный перевод - вариант использования

Comment: UseCase это не про MVP, а про Clean Architecture.
https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture

Comment: Неплохой перевод на русский язык&nbsp;&mdash; сценарий. Описывает, что действия пользователя и ответы системы. Обычно сценарии это часть Технического Задания, на основании которых и проектируется архитектура приложения.

Comment: @miha_dev Use Case - это просто способ описаний требований. Для любой архитектуры.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UseCase - это бизнес-логика, которую вы можете описать простым предложением.

Например, "Добавить платежку", "Удалить платежку", "Отредактировать платежку".
Канонического определения Interactor нет. Кто-то приравнивает UseCase и Interactor.

Я сторонник подхода, что Interactor = UseCase feature facade.

То есть для нашего примера есть PaymentsInteractor, который включает вышеописанные UseCases.
Такой подход удобден тем, что получается более стройная и упорядоченная структура бизнес-логики. Если UseCase - это отдельный класс, то ваше приложение может быть заполонено этим бойлерплэйт кодом. Кроме того, когда у вас ситуации, что один UseCase зависит от другого и т.д., вам все равно как-то придется их объединять.

Comment: спасибо, теперь стало понятно)

Comment: Забавно, Евгений, я раньше думал, что на SO у вас бурная деятельность, а рейтинг давно перевалил за 10К :). Некогда?

Comment: @CoolMind некогда =(

Answer (score 3):

Это сценарий использования приложения или часть приложения.
Например, Use Case для приложения банкомата будет выглядеть примерно так:

- Войти в аккаунт (положив карточку и набирая ПИН код)
- Узнать баланс
- Положить деньги
- Вывести деньги
- Оплачивать счета. (за моб. телефон, за коммунальные услуги и тд.и тп.)
- (и другие действия если имеются)
- Выйти из аккаунта (вытащив карточку)

А Use Case для переключателя будет так:

- Включить
- Выключить

Исходя из этого сценария уже можно создать архитектуру приложения, можно нарисовать диаграммы (диаграмма деятельности, диаграмма последовательности, диаграмма класса и тд.).

Answer (score 1):

UseCase - это "способ использования", бизнес-логика. В видео-презентации Uncle Bob приводит пример с размещением заказа. И это может быть любой заказ, даже не в приложении, а например клерку в банке. То есть UseCase описывает последовательность действий для размещения заказа.

Для класса делающего это Uncle Bob ввел название Interactor. 
То есть это то же самое (Interactor = UseCase).